# Grab JSON value using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

Below is the result of the code written below, where I would like to grab the first id element, and equal that to a php variable such as $customerID = whats in the green
[image]

Below is how this json data is generated:

```
try {
 $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
      'customer' => $customer->id,
      'amount'   => $amount,
      'currency' => 'cad',
            'capture' => 'false',

      'description'=>  $courseTitle

  ));

 $charge_json =  $charge->__toJSON();
 $charge_json->_values['id'];

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($charge_json);
echo "</pre>";

} catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
  // The card has been declined
  $stripChargeValid = false;
  echo "failed";

}
```

Note:

The notice of error found on line 58 is the below line:

```
 $charge_json->_values['id'];
```

The reason I did the following line was because at its core the json data being populated was protected and hence i would not be able to grab the id:

```
 $charge_json =  $charge->__toJSON();
```

Comment: please mark your question with the correct tags next-time around

Comment: okay, but if im not mistaking the javascript tag was valid because json is javascript

Comment: It is 'Javascript' in a sense but the tag is not valid

Comment: Json is not javascript. Json is essentially a standardized data format (think xml). Javascript is an actual programming language (completely separate from Java).

Answer (score 2):

You need to `json_decode()` the $customer data (the json image you posted). Afterwards you can access the id by `$customer->id`. Call `print_r()` on the json_decoded $customer to see its structure.

Comment: thanks, i did manage to grab the customer->id thanks to your help, but rather what i need is the charge id

Comment: To get charge id you would do `$customer->source->id` Again, print the full $customer so you can see the structure.

Comment: thanks. what i am implying was could di do $charge->id instead

Comment: You're not understanding the structure. You must understand the structure in order to know how to access specific data. To to do that, you would have to `$customer = json_decode($customer); //Where $customer is response from stripe` <br> and then `$customer = $customer->source` ..so that now `$customer->id EQUALS the charge id`. See how this was wasteful though and unneeded?

Comment: thanks for your response. i unfortunately receive the following error : Trying to get property of non-object when using $customer->source->id, the charge id doesnt seem to appear when using customer i only manage to get it to display using  $charge_json =  $charge->__toJSON();
 $charge_json->_values['id'];

Comment: Replace $customer with $charge dude. Whatever variable holds the response from Stripe.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode).

I've made you an example. [PHPaste Snippet](https://phpaste.ga/paste/e88cbb).